# Undefined behavior using strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I am using strtok() the string tokenizer

input is like say

```
"a,b,c,d|12,34,56,78"
```

I am doing

```
      char * cols;
      char * vals;
      $char col_val_temp[1024] = {0};
      $char col_val[1024] = {0};

      cols = strtok(input,"|");
      vals = strtok('\0',"|");
      // now vals will have "12,34,56,78"
      strcpy(col_val_temp,vals);
      strcpy(col_val,col_val_temp);
```

and in the later part of code I am again using `strtok` on `vals` but, I see in debugger that suddenly out of no where the value of `col_val` becomes null while there is data present in `col_val_temp`. I have not done any operation on `col_val` string, so I don't understand why the data in there is getting lost.

Can someone please explain why I am getting this behavior and how to overcome this.
I am stuck because of this.

Thanks !!!

Comment: We can't explain anything unless you show us the code. We need to see how you declared the variables, and how you allocated memory. Please provide a complete sample.

Comment: You must show the declarations of all variables you use. They're not obvious. Also note that the second call to `strtok()` is better written with `NULL` as its first argument, a character literal is quite odd there.

Comment: here my concern is that how col_val_temp has its value whereas col_val has nothing. I am not doing anything in the code with col_val. Yes, I am using strtok on "vals".

Comment: @David Heffernan....its esql code. The values that are used in the databse are initialised with $

Comment: When you say "col_val becomes null", do you mean contents of `col_val` array become 0, or do you mean that `col_val` actually has pointer-value NULL (which seems impossible, as it is local array variable...)?

Comment: @hyde...ya the "col_val" has nothing in it whereas "col_val_temp" has the values.

Comment: @David ... In the last while loop the I am facing this behavior.

Comment: Please please please post a short program that illustrates the behaviour. And clearly mark where it occurs. Your edit just confuses things. You need to try harder with your question asking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan....i am trying to replicate this using a simpler program but it behaves normally. So, I cannot post an example for this. Thats why i have pasted the original code where I am facing this issue. Also, even after replacing with NULL I am getting same problem.

Comment: And what about the buffer overrun that Klas identified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (at least) one buffer overrun problem in your code.

You do a `strcpy` to `seqno`. `seqno` is declared only one character long, so the string terminator will probably overwrite the pointer value of `cols`.